# Django - Relation "relation" does not exist. Cannot run python manage.py migrate?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

So I was being stupid and I went to delete one of the tables in my django app so opened up psql and ran "Drop table ;" and dropped the table. Then I deleted my model and ran "python manage.py migrate" and I get this error...

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "textchange_myuser" does not exist
```

among other stuff above it.

So now I can't delete the table properly and I can't get it back. What do I do?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried adding `--fake` options?

Comment: I have not, how can I use those?

Comment: just run `python manage.py migrate yourapp --fake`

Comment: What exactly does it do?

Comment: it will tell django that "OK, this migration has been applied, but do not actually alter your database"

Comment: It appears to have worked, if you want to type out an answer I will mark it as correct :) thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment, in your situation you might run:

```
python manage.py migrate yourapp --fake
```

to "fake" applying the migration but not actually alter your database.

You can read more [HERE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---fake)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I deleted a table from postgres and then django was unable to detect the change. I tried everything but django didn't created a new table. Finally I fixed this with some alternate way.

login to your database create table manually.
- Get the create command from django itself.

```
python manage.py sqlmigrate 'yourapp' 001
```

this will give you the initial command django used to create the table.

one by one get all the migrations and execute commands on database by command line.