# Django Migration not Applying to Postgress in RDS on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: django, django-models

I've edited my Django model.py with 2 new models, MyMap and CustomMap. When I migrate the local database and run a local server I can modify records via shell or the admin client.

After deploying to the AWS environment I get the following error when I try to add a MyMap or CustomMap in the admin from example.com/admin/as_app/custommap/:

> ProgrammingError at /admin/as_app/custommap/
>
> relation "as_app_custommap" does not exist
>
> LINE 1: SELECT COUNT('*') AS "__count" FROM "as_app_custommap"

When I deploy to elastic beanstalk all migrations are auto generated and ran. I can confirm via ssh into an EC2 instance like so:

```
(venv)[root@ip-#### django_folder]# python manage.py makemigrations
No changes detected
```

I also confirmed that my changes are actually in models.py:

```
(venv)[root@ip-#### django_folder]# vi as_app/models.py

class MyMap(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(default='', max_length=200, unique=True)
    def name_and_id(self):
        return self.name + " (" + str(self.pk) + ")"
    kml_file = models.FileField(upload_to='as_app/my_maps', blank=True, default='')
 
class CustomMap(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Map Name', default='', max_length=200, unique=True)
    def location(self):
        return u'<a href="' + settings.BASE_URL + u'map/custom_view/' + self.name + u'">' + settings.BASE_URL + u'map/custom_view/' + self.name + u'</a>'
    location.allow_tags = True
    widget1 = models.FileField(upload_to='as_app/custom_maps', blank=True, default='')
    widget2 = models.FileField(upload_to='as_app/custom_maps', blank=True, default='')
    widget3 = models.FileField(upload_to='as_app/custom_maps', blank=True, default='')
    widget4 = models.FileField(upload_to='as_app/custom_maps', blank=True, default='')
    widget5 = models.FileField(upload_to='as_app/custom_maps', blank=True, default='')
    widget6 = models.FileField(upload_to='as_app/custom_maps', blank=True, default='')
    widget7 = models.FileField(upload_to='as_app/custom_maps', blank=True, default='')
    widget8 = models.FileField(upload_to='as_app/custom_maps', blank=True, default='')
    widget9 = models.FileField(upload_to='as_app/custom_maps', blank=True, default='')
    widget10 = models.FileField(upload_to='as_app/custom_maps', blank=True, default='')

class ExternalData(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Data Name', default='', max_length=200, unique=True)
    location = models.URLField()
    def clickable_location(self):
        return u'<a href="' + self.location + u'">' + self.location + u'</a>'
    clickable_location.allow_tags = True 
...
```

However, when I inspect the database I can see that the models are still missing:

```
(venv)[root@ip-#### django_folder]# python manage.py inspectdb

from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

class AsAppExternaldata(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=200)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'as_app_externaldata'
...
```

Lastly via the shell I can reproduce the error I received in the admin client and confirm that other models are working fine:

```
(venv)[root@ip-#### django_folder]# python manage.py shell
In [1]: import django
 
In [2]: from as_app.models import *
 
In [3]: django.setup()
 
In [4]: ExternalData
Out[4]: as_app.models.ExternalData
 
In [5]: MyMap
Out[5]: as_app.models.MyMap
 
In [6]: ExternalData.objects.all() 
Out[6]: []
 
In [7]: MyMap.objects.all() 
/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.pyc in execute(self, sql, params)
     62                 return self.cursor.execute(sql)
     63             else:
---> 64                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
     65
     66     def executemany(self, sql, param_list): 
 
ProgrammingError: relation "as_app_mymap" does not exist
LINE 1: ...app_mymap"."name", "as_app_mymap"."kml_file" FROM "as_app_my...
```

I've tried migrating using the --fake flag suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33555013/django-relation-relation-does-not-exist-cannot-run-python-manage-py-migrate).

Also tried running sqlmigrate manually specifying my migration as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29672190/django-error-relation-users-user-does-not-exist).

I tried doing a lot of searching for anything related to:

> django inspectdb not showing model

... and similar phrases but no luck.

Let me know if there is anything else that would be helpful to try or show.

Comment: Did you trying running`migrate`? `(venv)[root@ip-#### django_folder]# python manage.py migrate`

Comment: Yep, I get a message saying there are no migrations to apply.

Comment: Getting the same issue today. Ever find a solution?